# Display HTML content without a window in WIN32

Tags: c++, html, winapi

I want to display HTML text inside a RECT structure within a win32 window. I have found a lot of APIs which helps me render HTML in a separate window, but my requirement is that we dont have to assign a separate window handle for the HTML being displayed.

Comment: Clearly there must be a window handle somewhere. Your requirement appears to be that you render HTML to a window but do not fill the entire client area of that window.

That's simple enough to achieve. You need to add code to the `WM_PAINT` handler for the window. The code you add will render the HTML to the appropriate part of the window's client area.

Answer (score 1):

The `RECT` structure is basically two points representing a rectangle, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can't store any other kind of information inside of a `RECT`.

Perhaps what you need to do requires creating an `EDITTEXT` control, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use it display the HTML as text. You can use the values from the `RECT` to define the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` parameters of the `EDITTEXT`.